# How to checkout feature branch at initial stage after many commits

Tags: git, gitlab

I have created one feature branch from master branch,
I have committed many code in 3 to 4 commits. Now I've observed that some existing feature are not working which is working fine in master branch.

I have tried to checkout at my first commit by using command "git checkout hash"
But i found in my first commit also that existing feature was not working.

Now i have to checkout the original code when first time my feature branch was created and there was no any commit from my end.

How can i checkout the code when the branch was just created?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `git checkout master`?

Comment: No, i want to checkout my feature branch when it is freshly created, where there is no commit from my side.

Comment: If you created your branch from master as you mentioned, your branch *without* its original commits is **exactly** `master`

Comment: I have tested that functionality in master branch and it is working fine. but when i created feature branch from master, i have observed that some existing functionality is not working. i have committed many things in my feature branch. so i want to checkout when my feature branch was just created and no any commits of my code

Comment: Yes, I get that. But when you branch off `master`, git creates a new pointer pointing at the same commit. So it's at this point true identity. Maybe check if your local `master` is up-to-date, you might have tested on an outdated local version.

Comment: so i have to do git checkout master? but i'm confused , everything is working fine.
Let me try this,
I will checkout with hash of my first commit. then try to remove my code from each file and see from where it is creating problem

Comment: This sounds like a hard way to recreate (with potential errors) something git provides. And you didn't adress my last suggestion. *Where* or *how* did you test `master`? locally?

Comment: Yes, i have tested master branch locally.
git checkout < master branch >

Comment: My branch is up to date with master branch, as no any code is merged in that after i created feature branch

Comment: Please double-check it(s up-to-date with `git checkout master` and `git pull`, (and build things, or clear any "caches" if needed, don't know your context) then test again. You *might* have tested an outdated local version.

Comment: @RomainValeri : Thank you for your help, I have compared my master branch and local branch,
After observing each file committed initially, i found mistake which was not even caught in compilation, and that was creation the issue. Finally old functionality is working fine now in my branch as well.

I have learned many new thing in this post. I'm appreciating everyone's effort to guide me. :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you need the specific state of `master` from the time you started your feature branch.

Did your `master` branch change since you branched off your current feature branch?

If the answer is **no**, than @RomainValeri is completely right and you could (and should) start a new branch from master and are good to go, because that's the exact state of your feature branch before anything happened.
(tbh you should do this anyway ... if your feature wasn't implemented yet you should be able to start from scratch even if master changed)

Nevertheless - if you want to get this done on your feature branch with resetting the state to the specific commit of master **before** you added your changes, try resetting the branch:
(SIDENOTE: I propose a hard reset, so all changes you did will be lost ... I recommend to start a new branch from your current feature branch before you continue!)

1. look at your git history with `git log` ... u should see something like that:

```sh
$ git log --pretty=oneline

33d3a1c7c0ca4667262fc26ecc01bafcf5dedec9 (HEAD -> feature/my-super-feature, origin/feature/my-super-feature) fix: I fixed somthing I did wrong with this commit
ce6ffa2d59b087e106f726e340e72ab935b0ebb7 feat: another awesome feature for you guys
ce6ffa2d59b087e106f726e340e72ab935b0ebb7 feat: some awesome feature improving our app
a2c880d20c6010ac6f651c5a8bc45f43adaf5658 (origin/master, master) docs: the commit you want to reset to
9fbb874dc6e1f926e8e3d78d260a226bd06f953f Merge branch 'feat/some-legacy-feature' into 'master'
```

2. Now you reset your feature branch targeting the commit-hash of master ... in this case this would be: `git reset --hard a2c880d20c6010ac6f651c5a8bc45f43adaf5658`
   per default reset would be a soft reset, meaning that your reset targets the commited code-state, but your changes would simply be set to "uncommited", that's why we use the `--hard` option. Now everything will be set back to that very commit you chose!

Comment: Thank you friends, I have compared my master branch and local branch,
After observing each file committed initially, i found mistake which was not even caught in compilation, and that was creation the issue. Finally old functionality is working fine now in my branch as well.

I have learned many new thing in this post. I'm appreciating everyone's effort to guide me. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Now i have to checkout the original code when first time my feature branch was created and there was no any commit from my end.

Say

```
git merge-base feature master
```

Write down the answer. It is an SHA number.

Now

```
git checkout <thatNumber>
```